# XAMPP define a work directory and use it

Tags: php, xampp, wamp

How can I define my work path in XAMPP so I could write my code there and test it.

Example: In WAMP, I just added the folder 'courses01' in the 'wamp/www/' directory.
Can I do the same in XAMPP ? Just add my courses folder in the system files? But where? and how can I access them in the 'localhost/xampp' menu??

I need this so I could work with my PHP files from my courses :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your **folders/php_file.php** in `xampp\htdocs`. then access `http://localhost/folder` or `http://localhost/php_file.php` in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do:

Step 1:
Create a dir in your Home folder usually located here:

`C:/Users/Yourname/www/courses01`

Step 2: Edit virtual hosts located in:
`C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Yourname\www\courses01"
    ServerName courses01.dev
     <Directory "C:\Users\Yourname\www\courses01">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Step 3: Modify hosts file located in:

`C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

add a line:

127.0.0.1             courses09.dev

Step 4: Restart apache